# How to print the 3rd column from multiple files on the y axis with a common axis in XMGRACE (gfortran, Linux terminal)

Tags: linux, plot, data-analysis, xmgrace

I have three files of the format '.dat' (available in the link down below), I need to plot their third columns on Y axis while they all have a common first column ( so a common X axis ), how to plot all of them in the same plot on XMGRACE. I know how to plot the third column from a single '.dat' file by `xmgrance -block file.dat -bxy 'x-axis column number: y-axis column number`. But is there a similar code for multiple files.

Link for files : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iuNdjnyUjphh5WUf-3oVubH0fm0zut-P?usp=sharing

I should get a graph like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You either pre-process them to make them two-column or you repeat the `-block [...] -bxy [...]`  instructions for each file, like this:

```
xmgrace -block file1.dat -bxy 1:3 -block file2.dat -bxy 1:3 -block file3.dat -bxy 1:3
```